# C++ functional programming code snippets

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, functional-programming, variadic-templates

I have been working on a project called: *Functional Programming Features of C++11/14* (for one of my subjects at university).
There are several existing sources and similar presentations about such topics and I found one
not so long ago which contained several code snippets that I haven't managed to understand completely (and somehow they can be connected to functional programming). Snippets **A** and **B** belonged to *recursion* and **C** belonged to *lazy evaluation*. I'd like to share them with you below:

**Snippet A**:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    static int const val = N * Factorial<N - 1>::val;
};

template <>
struct Factorial <0> {
    static int const val = 1;
};

int main() {
    int factorial_of_6 = Factorial<6>::val;
    std::cout << factorial_of_6 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Was the point here compile time evaluation (in order to avoid runtime computations and improve performance)?
Or are there other advantages, too?

**Snippet B**:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int ...>
struct my_sum;

template <>
struct my_sum <> {
    static const int value {0};
};

template <int i, int ... tail>
struct my_sum <i, tail ...> {
    static const int value = i + my_sum<tail ...>::value;
};

int main() {
    int sum {my_sum<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::value};
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Same question applies as above.

And here is another snippet which is maybe similar:

**Snippet C**:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
void some_function (Args ...) {
    std::cout << sizeof...(Args) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    some_function ("Every little thing gonna be alright...", 1.0 / 0.0);
    return 0;
}
```

*"The presentation said: C++ is eager but the following will work."*
Is its point that until I don't care about the given expressions I can tell the quantity of them?

Please, be as specific and detailed as possible, and thank you very much for your patience and help in advance. :)

Comment: For C, args are not lazy evaluated. There are evaluated (then optimization with *as-if* rule may discard them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Snippet A**

This is called `Template Metaprogramming`, which is basically a technique using templates to generate code at compile time. This increases run time performance, because the calculations aren't done at run time, but rather at compile time.

*Snippet A* calculates the factorial of a given number at compile time:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    static int const val = N * Factorial<N - 1>::val;
};
```

This defines a `struct` `Factorial` as a template which takes an `int`. In that `struct`, there is a `static const` variable. The variable is `static`, so that you don't have to create an instance of `Factorial` to access it, you can just use `Factorial::val` instead of

```
Factorial factorial;
factorial.val;
```

The variable is `const` because the factorial of a given number is always the same, and because the project won't compile if it isn't `const`, because the compiler has no way of knowing if you change the variable someplace else.

The variable has a value of `N * Factorial<N - 1::val;`, which basically multiplies `N` with the factorial of the previous number. This is because of how factorials are defined (`3! = 2! * 3 = 1! * 2 * 3 = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6`).

```
template <>
struct Factorial <0> {
    static int const val = 1;
};
```

This defines a fully specialized `struct` for `N = 0`. This is really important, or else the recursion used in the previous function will never stop.

Then, getting the factorial of a number `N` is easy, `Factorial<N>::val`. This will be calculated at compile time.

---

**Snippet B**

This is also `Template Metaprogramming`.

```
template <int ...>
struct my_sum;
```

This defines an empty template `struct` which takes an `int...` (a `Parameter Pack`), so that it can be specialized (see next point).

```
template <>
struct my_sum <> {
    static const int value {0};
};
```

This specializes the `struct` `my_sum`, when no template arguments are given (this is because of the `Parameter Pack`, which can be empty, and so the template arguments will be empty when the `Parameter Pack` is expanded). The `value` is `static` and `const` because of the same reasons as before, and it is `0` initialized using an `initializer list` (for an `int`, there is no difference between `int i = 0;` and `int i{ 0 };`).

```
template <int i, int ... tail>
struct my_sum <i, tail ...> {
    static const int value = i + my_sum<tail ...>::value;
};
```

This defines the `struct` `my_sum` as a template which takes 2 template arguments, an `int` and a `int` parameter pack. This is used to get the value of the first value of a parameter pack, because you can't index a parameter pack (it's not an array). Then, `value` is initialized as `i` (the first value of the pack) plus the `value` of the other values as parameter pack, which is expanded (using the `...`):

```
int sum = my_sum<1, 2, 3>::value;
```

This calls `my_sum<int i, int... tail>`, `i` is `1` and `tail` is `2, 3`. `value` is `i + my_sum<tail...>::value`, so it is `1 + my_sum<2, 3>`. `my_sum<2, 3>` calls the same function again, `2 + my_sum<3>::value`. Now we have `1 + 2 + my_sum<3>::value`. `my_sum<3>::value` calls again the same function, but now the parameter pack is empty! So `value` is `1 + 2 + 3 + my_sum<>::value`. `my_sum<>::value` is `0` (as defined) and so `value = 1 + 2 + 3 + 0`.

---

**Snippet C**

The expression is evaluated, but the program doesn't crash because the expression when evaluated, is a `double`. Only when the expression is an `int` does it crash with a `Integer division by zero exception`. If you were to do this:

```
int zero = 0; 
double d = 1.0 / zero;
```

Then `d` would have the value `inf`.

The function `some_function` is a template function which takes as template parameter a parameter pack. Then it calls `sizeof...` which counts the elements in the parameter pack, and outputs it using`std::cout`.

Comment: Thank You very much for your detailed response! But I'd like to ask one more if You don't mind: I got your explanation about C but does it even make sense if I use integers? The expression will be evaluated and the program crashes. Was that even similar to lazy evaluation at all? (Just like Jarod42 mentioned above.)

Comment: @ZsoltLászló I don't think so, because as Jarod42 has said, there is no builtin lazy evaluation in C++

Comment: Understood, thank You. By the way, I've managed to run the code since that: putting -O3 to the compiler options made it possible to avoid exceptions (and the output was the expected 2).